# Read and echo on some line Bash

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Hello I want to read a command and print it on some line.

**Example:** 
I use a function where I read values into `a` and `b` then echo these values and the result of some operation:

```
1. $ 5 plus 5
2. $  = 10
```

On 1. line I am reading to variables `a` and `b`, after that I hit enter and `echo` the result but on a new line. Read command need enter and enter in terminal give you new line.

How it should look like:

```
1. $ 5 plus 5 = 10
```

I tried to use sed with no luck.

EDIT: I am using simple:

```
$read a b c
#a=5 b=plus c=5
```

Comment: What is your command to read from string `5 plus 5`?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is possible without modifying the internals of Bash. Internally, when you execute a command, Bash moves the cursor to the next line. You might have to modify the source such that pressing enter will not yield line feed or carriage return characters.

Comment: I was wondering it is possible. So I can use workaround: '$clear && echo $a $b $c $result' and it will be look like a result is added to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ANSI escape codes to go up one line and clear the line:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p 'equation: ' operand1 operation operand2
# magic to transform "plus" to "+" left to the reader
let answer="$operand1 $operation $operand2"
echo -e "\033[F\033[K$operand1 $operation $operand2 = $answer"
```

ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Upon reflection, I'd break that into 2 statements for some clarity:

```
echo -ne "\033[F\033[K"   # move the cursor and clear the line
echo "$operand1 $operation $operand2 = $answer"
```